# Do I have to worry about my logs containing long request for signalr/poll and signalr/connect

Tags: asp.net-mvc, signalr

In my logs I have requests to signalr/poll and signalr/connect that take around 30 seconds.

The applications had some isues recently caused by thread starvation. Might these requests be the root cause or is it an expected behaviour and is the duration normal?

When I request the site with chrome I see websocket traffic so I gues it is running ok for most clients.

The applications is accessed via vpn and sometimes the connection is bad. Could this be a reason for falling back to long polling?

[image]

Comment: Signalr tries to connect with websocket. if it fails or browser does not support, it triess other protocols. You can customize order or eliminate protocols which you don't want `$.connection.hub.start( { transport: ['webSockets', 'serverSentEvents'] });` This will try first websocket then serversentEvents. May be your vpn does not support websocket.

Comment: Do the trequests to signalr/poll indicate that long polling is used?

Comment: Yes signalr/poll is just by longpolling.

Comment: I bet SignalR is falling back to long polling due to your company firewall not allowing web sockets

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have enough threads, you end up in a deadlock, and the app will start to error out, and not work properly. At that point you would be forced to restart your AppPool, or web server. If your application is falling back to long polling, and a client is connected but not doing anything the poll will remain open until it gets a response, or if there is a timeout configured (default is 30 seconds I believe) will close on timeout. I would try restarting your AppPool and see if that helps, if not there is something wrong in the transportation layer, it should only need to fall back to long polling in extreme circumstances